# Does passing address to a pointer results in type promotion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

While initializing the pointer `p` in the given statement

```
int a[10], *p;
p = &a[0];
```

I am in doubt that whether the type of `&a[0]` is `pointer to int` or is it `int`?
I came to this confusion after reading this:

> Using `a` as a pointer to the first element in the array, we can modify a[0]: `*a = 7;`.

NOTE: I am interested to know the type of `&a[0]`.

Comment: `a[0]` is an int, so `&a[0]` is a pointer to an int.  `&(something)` is a pointer to that thing.  What you're confused about is assignment to a pointer, since assignment works differently when `*` prefixes something

Comment: Down voter leave your comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&a[0]` is a pointer to `int`. Here are the interpretation steps for that:

- `&a[0]` is parsed as `&(a[0])` because the subscript operator `[]` binds more tightly than the address operator `&`.
- `a` is an array, but it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element in this case. (It would not be converted if it were the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or `&` or were a string literal used to initialize an array.)
- `a[0]` takes the pointer and becomes an lvalue for the first element (element 0).
- `&(a[0])` is a pointer to `a[0]`. Since we know `a[0]` is an `int`, a pointer to `a[0]` is a pointer to an `int`.

Then `p` is assigned the value of `&a[0]`. Thus, `p` is a pointer to the first element of `a`.

Since `p` is a pointer to the first element of `a`, `*p` is an lvalue for that element. An lvalue can be used on the left side of an assignment to assign to the object it refers to.

Comment: In the statement `p = a`, isn't `a` is of `integer array type` and promoted to `pointer to int`?

Comment: @haccks This is array decaying into a pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1461466/1708801

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; I only want to know about type of `a` when it is assigning to a pointer `p`.

Comment: @haccks It will be an `int *`.

Comment: @haccks: In `p = a`, `a` is converted to a pointer to `int`. I simply call it a conversion, not a promotion or a decay. Any array object in an expression (not just a simple identifier; it could be computed in various ways, such as dereferencing a pointer to an array) is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of the array unless the array is the operand of `sizeof`, of `_Alignof`, or `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Comment: Yes, in the statement `p = a`, the type of `a` itself isn't really relevant. The type of the *expression* `a`, in this particular context, is pointer to `int`, because of the automatic conversion. Even though the type of `a` is an array type, the type of the *expression* `a` is not necessarily the same, and in this case, is not.

Answer (score 1):

[`&`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Faddre.htm) is the address  operator so, `&a[0]` is taking the address of the first element of the array `a`, so it is an `int *`. Since `[]` has [higher precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than `*` you can read it as follows:

```
&(a[0])
```

which may be more clear. The case where you have:

```
p = a ;
```

works do to the array [decaying to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461466/1708801).

Answer (score 1):

for historical reasons

```
 p = a;
```

and

```
p = &a[0]
```

are equivalent.   Beware that

```
auto q = &a;
```

is also legal but the type of q will NOT be int* but rather int[10] *.  This is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: `auto q = &a` is not C. This question is tagged with C and not with C++.

Answer (score 0):

The address of `a[0]` is of type pointer to an integer.
You can modify the first element of the array because `*a` is equivalent to `*(a + 0)` which is nothing but `a[0]`.